# Why doesn't downloaded font work on website?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I downloaded 2 fonts from dafont.com and coded

```
html-selector {
 font-family: font-name;
}
```

The font name appears in the PHPStorm font-family list when I'm coding. But the fonts are not working when rendered in html/css.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the font accessible to the browser?

Comment: Sorry Brad, I don't understand your question. I downloaded and installed it to my PC (Windows).

Comment: PS they work in MS Word.

Comment: Check my answer. No need to install, just save to your project and use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to download a font. You have to let your page (CSS file) know where to get the new font as indicated in your css `font-family`.

I'm assuming you downloaded `font-name-Regular.ttf` and stored it in the `./fonts/` folder.

In your css file (preferably at the top) use:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font-name';
  src: url('./fonts/font-name-Regular.ttf');
}
```

#### NOTE:

Ensure you always have fall-back fonts, just incase the `@font-face` rule is not supported by the browser.

**Example:**

```
html-selector {
    font-family: font-name, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I got the otf font file to work with IE, but not the ttf file.  I got neither of them to work with with Chrome or Firefox.  I've been reading online about WOFF/WOFF2: do I have to use only WOFF/WOFF2 files with Chrome and Firefox?  Can ttf/otf files be converted to WOFF?

Comment: You can convert ttf font files to another font format. A quick search on Google will put you in the right direction. Also you should use more than one font format so the browser would pick what it can use. **NOTE:** Arrange them in order of size; smallest first...